# Asp.net sql connection error in two pages

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a restaurant website on asp.net.... i have two table in database . recipe and review... i have fetch data from review table and in there i connected the database connection

```
using con = 
    new SqlConnection(
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString
   ); 
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MCN", con); 
da.Fill(dt);
```

now in recipe page i want to fetch data from recipe table.. i m using the same code except the table name ..and i have error saying that con , da already used..changed the name ..bt still facing the problem...May be i made a conceptual mistake as i m very new in coding.

Comment: _What exactly does the error say?_

Answer (score 0):

try

```
// `using` scopes `con` variable and automatically disposes of it (closes)
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString)) {
  con.Open();  // you must open the connection before using it
  using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MCN", con)) {
    da.Fill(dt);
  } // we also want to automatically clean up our SqlDataAdapter
} // even on exception, connection is closed automatically here. nice, huh?
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be closing the connection after retrieveing data

Comment: exit the project and then started again !! worked for me